# Google Apps Script won't remove background/highlight color from bullet points in document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm using Google Apps Script edit a document. Different parts have different background colors. I want to make all the background white.

When I run the following function, all of the background changes to white, except for the bullet points (the glyphs).

```
function editDoc(documentId)
 var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
 var body = newDoc.getBody();
 var listItems = body.getListItems()
  listItems.forEach(function(item){
    const color = item.getAttributes()['BACKGROUND_COLOR']
    if(color!='#ffffff'){
      item.setAttributes({'BACKGROUND_COLOR': "#ffffff"})
      console.log(item.getText() + " " + item.getGlyphType() +  " " + item.getAttributes()['BACKGROUND_COLOR'])
    }
  })
```

The console.log output is:
`Submit a flow and pressure test report  BULLET #ffffff`
So it looks like the color has changed to white, but when I go in the document, everything is white except the actual bullets themselves.

The input looks like this:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cTv0.png)

The output looks like this:

[image: 1]

In addition to the above I have also tried:
`body.editAsText().setBackgroundColor(0,body.getText().length-1,null)`

and for each loop through each paragraph with:
`paragraph.setAttributes({'BACKGROUND_COLOR': "#ffffff"})`

All have the same result of removing the background color from everything except the glyphs

I have tried with many different docs files. All have the same result.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from your question and your showing script. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, don't worry, your English is good. I have updated the post to be clearer.
Can you see the output image? I'm expecting the background color to be completely gone,

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. I believe that you updated your question from `In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your sample input and output situations you expect?`. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected input and output situations. Is `The input looks like this: Input` is your sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, is `The output looks like this:` your expected output situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: The input is any Google docs file with bullet points and text highlighted. The output is the same file, except the text highlights are gone, but the bullets are still highlighted

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. From your reply, unfortunately, I couldn't understand where I can see the input and output situations you expect. But, I would like to try to understand your sample input and output situations for understanding your question. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.